# How to hide the column header of a sharepoint document library in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I hide the column header of a sharepoint document library in Sharepoint Online.

Gr. P

Answer (score 2):

If you are in modern experience, you can use the `hideColumnHeader` element in JSON formatting via *Format current view > Advanced mode*.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": true
}
```

Reference: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

In classic experience, you can use CSS, JavaScript/JQuery code to hide the column headers. Here is a sample script for your reference:

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table[summary='Documents'] tr:eq(0)").hide();
});
</script>
```

[image]

Reference: [How to Hide Column Headers in SharePoint List View Web Parts using CSS, jQuery?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/how-to-hide-column-headers-in-sharepoint-list-views.html)

Comment: Updated answer due to a previous mistake.